# Как расположить td в центре экрана?

Tags: html, css

Привет! Всем! Как расположить td по центру экрана так, что бы этот способ работал на IE6?
т.е. к примеру сам экран на 1200px, а td 650px

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="b-update__block">
      <h1>outdated version</h1>
      <p>You are using outdated version of the web browser. This version does not support many of the modern technologies. We recommend to update your version of the browser:</p>
      <div class="b-update__line"></div>
      <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Google Chrome" class="b-update__browser">
          <img src="images/inhtml/chrome.png" alt="Google Chrome" title="Google Chrome"><span>Google Chrome</span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Internet Explorer" class="b-update__browser">
          <img src="images/inhtml/explorer.png" alt="Internet Explorer" title="Internet Explorer"><span>Internet Explorer</span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Opera" class="b-update__browser">
          <img src="images/inhtml/opera.png" alt="Opera" title="Opera"><span>Opera</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```css
table {
  width: 1200px;
}
.b-update__block {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="b-update__block">
        <h1>outdated version</h1>
        <p>You are using outdated version of the web browser. This version does not support many of the modern technologies. We recommend to update your version of the browser:</p>
        <div class="b-update__line"></div>
        <div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Google Chrome" class="b-update__browser">
            <img src="images/inhtml/chrome.png" alt="Google Chrome" title="Google Chrome"><span>Google Chrome</span>
          </a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Internet Explorer" class="b-update__browser">
            <img src="images/inhtml/explorer.png" alt="Internet Explorer" title="Internet Explorer"><span>Internet Explorer</span>
          </a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Скачать Opera" class="b-update__browser">
            <img src="images/inhtml/opera.png" alt="Opera" title="Opera"><span>Opera</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```